# Why has Ctrl+F (Find) in Visual Studio 2010 stopped automatically searching for the currently selected text?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Normally if you select some text in the Visual Studio editor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, when the Find and Replace modeless dialog appears, your selected text is automatically shown in the "Find what:" textbox/dropdown.

For some strange reason this has stopped working - is there a setting that controls this?

Comment: FYI you might like the CTRL+F3 shortcut :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not stop doing that, and you did not tell it yet to use the selected text: Go to *Tools* → *Options* → *Find and Replace*, and check the "Automatically populate Find..." option.

Comment: That used to be enabled by default.

Comment: I don't understand how it got disabled...and now it is magically re-enabled :)

Comment: Even it is not working in my case. 
I checked that option too.

Comment: I got it enabled but it still doesn't work, only CTRL+F3

Comment: Regarding "It did not stop doing that, and you did not tell it yet to use the selected text."
Yes, it did. For me, this option has always been enabled, then CTRL+F suddenly stopped working according to its settings.

Answer (score 3):

If you checked the "Automatically populate Find..." option and it still does not work,
then you need to reset your Visual Studio settings to solve the problem:

- In Visual Studio: Window menu / Reset Window Layout
- In a command prompt with admininstrator privilages (use your own path to devenv.exe in the `cd` command below):

  `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE"`

  `devenv /resetsettings`

  `devenv /setup`

(The idea came from here: https://blog.parkercomp.com/2009/11/how-to-fix-visual-studio-when-ctrl-f.html)

Comment: had this issue in VS 2019. Ctrl-F definitely did not pre-populate the Find field. The prepopulate option was checked. Ctrl-F3 functioned itself, but did not fix Ctrl-F.  The steps here fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Tools* -> *Option* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard*, and then select Default and just the **RESET** button.

[image]

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: This works for me. I installed `VsVim` extension and find it hard to use, then I remove that extension, then my VS2022 cannot use Ctrl+F. This answer provided "Reset" works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me once when <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd> stopped populating the Find window with the current selection:

pressing <kbd>CTRL + F3</kbd> made it work again

Comment: This happened to me again, and this very same solution worked again for Quick Find, but not for Find in Files...

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio then

Goto Run
shortcut :Win+R

type temp and remove all temp then

Run Visual studio  Find command will work

[image]